# Trying to append a query onto a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008-R2

I have a csv of purchase IDs and in my database there is a table with these purchase IDs and there corresponding User IDs in our system.  I need these to run a more complicated query after that using.  I tried to bulk insert or run import wizard but I don't have permission.  My new idea is to create a #temp using SELECT INTO and then have the query inside that like below.

```
SELECT *
  INTO ##PurchaseIDs
  FROM
(
SELECT PurchaseID, UserID, Added
      FROM Users
     WHERE PurchaseID IN (
/* These are the csv IDs just copied and pasted in */
'49397828',
'49397883',
etc.
```

What happens is that there are ~55,000 IDs so I get this error.

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not
>   produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
>   extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
>   number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you
>   believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer
>   Support Services for more information.

It works if I upload about 30,000 so my new plan is to see if I can make a temp table, then append a new table to the end of that.  I am also open to other ideas on how to accomplish what I am looking to do.  I attached an idea of what I am thinking below.

```
INSERT *
  INTO ##PurchaseIDs
  FROM (
SELECT PurchaseID, UserID, Added
      FROM Users
     WHERE PurchaseID IN (
/* These are the OTHER csv IDS just copied and pasted in */
'57397828',
'57397883',
etc.
```

Comment: Can you not load the IDs into a table with BCP or SSIS package, then join to that table to insert data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a temp table and insert the values in `IN` clause to the temp table and Join the temp table to get the result

```
Create table #PurchaseIDs (PurchaseID int)

insert into #PurchaseIDs (PurchaseID)
Select '57397828'
Union All
Select '57397828'
Union All
......
values from csv
```

Now use `Exists` to check the existence of `PurchaseID` in temp table instead of `IN` clause

```
SELECT PurchaseID,
       UserID,
       Added
FROM   Users u
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   #PurchaseIDs p
               WHERE  u.PurchaseID = p.PurchaseID)
```